# Kinect v.2 for Windows shows in Device Manager, not in Kinect Studio?

Tags: windows, windows-10, kinect

I am on Windows 10 Pro, version 2004.

I am using a **Kinect v.2** with a Kinect for Windows adapter. I ran through the installation of the Kinect for Windows SDK version 1.8, followed by the Developer Toolkit (1.8) and Kinect Runtime (1.8) as well. After plugging in my Kinect and allowing the installation to complete, I visited my Device Manager and now have **"WDF KinectSensor Interface 0"** under the "Kinect for Windows" tab. So, it knows that a piece of equipment is plugged in, and it knows it's a Kinect.

However, when I activate Kinect Explorer (or any other application), I get the following message: **"Kinect Sensor Required, There are current no Kinect Sensors connected. Please plug in a sensor to begin using this application."**

[image]

What steps might I need to do at this point to troubleshoot my Kinect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using a Kinect v.2 with a Kinect for Windows adapter. I ran through the installation of the Kinect for Windows SDK version 1.8, followed by the Developer Toolkit (1.8) and Kinect Runtime (1.8) as well. After plugging in my Kinect and allowing the installation to complete, I visited my Device Manager and now have "WDF KinectSensor Interface 0" under the "Kinect for Windows" tab. So, it knows that a piece of equipment is plugged in, and it knows it's a Kinect.

The `Kinect SDK 1.8` does not support Kinect v2.

You must install the [Kinect SDK 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561)

> The Kinect for Windows SDK, driver, and runtime v1.8 are 100% compatible with Kinect for Windows v1.0, 1.5, 1.6, and 1.7 applications.

Source: [Kinect SDK v1.8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278)

> This release introduces support for the Kinect for Windows v2 sensor, and introduces a broad range of capabilities for developers.

Source: [Kinect SDK v2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561)